Transparent Jelly-like Material
How can I create a shader that looks like the blue box in this image?

This is what I did, but not even remotely similar:

For this example, one cloud is sufficient, and here is how I created the cloud:

The final result:


The glass should use a volume shader, the cloud should use the surface instead. (Assuming you don't want transparent clouds)

I'm a beginner, so I would appreciate it if you could explain more.

How I can use a volume shader for the glass?
Do you mean that instead of a "principled volume" I should use a mesh for the cloud?
Thanks!


Yes, the clouds as mesh.... It seems to me that there is a blue background, instead of the glass being blue itself. These clouds are way too white.

@DanielMöller thanks, I'll try with a mesh cloud.
